# Find the count of the like on Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.2, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I use facebook graph api and I encountered a problem relating to likes.

My request:
[image]

My goal is to find the count of the like. but the query timeout. What is the solution?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to find the count of the like

So you only want the overall *number* of likes, the counter, but not the individual likes?

Then you should [ask for the `summary` via field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes#read):

```
/{page_id}/feed?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(1)
```

For each feed item, you will get a `likes` data structure that looks like this:

```
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 12345
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the options below.

- Uncheck all the boxes and make the request again, if you give no error, go marking one by one until you find the problem.
- Try not to use the limit (999999) is very, I've had problems trying to get as much information in one query page.
- Make sure your access token created this with all the necessary permissions to your query.

I confess that I have never seen this error in the Graph API, is very generic and it is difficult to give you a more accurate suggestion.

Comment: Because it is too much like. For example, 1000+ and 1000*40(feed limit)=40,000. so facebook is not responding. worked when I tried to lower the feed limit. But sometimes like a total of more than 15,000 is still not responding. For example 15,000(like count) * 10(feed count) = 150,000. I do not know what to do. just once I would like to request...